# User is getting redirected to home page when entered URL manually in next js 14

Tags: next.js

I have written below code. When I navigate by clicking on links (Home, Jobs), it works fine, however if I enter URL manually eg.(https://localhost:3000/jobs), I get redirected to login page. How to fix this issue?

```
'use client';

import { getUserId } from '#/utils/user';
import { redirect, usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

function ValidateProtectedRoute({ children }) {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const userId = getUserId();
  if (!userId && pathname !== '/') {
    return redirect('/login');
  }
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

export default ValidateProtectedRoute;
```

When i debug, I get userId as well as pathname.

[image]

Comment: Test the `getUserId` function to see if it correctly returns a user ID on page reloads or when accessing URLs directly. If it's not returning the expected value, you'll need to fix this function.

Comment: I did console log of returned value from `getUserId` function. It prints expected value when I navigate by clicking on links. However, if I directly type URL, it gets redirected to login and prints undefined on server console. I don't know if I have marked component as 'client component' then why it prints value on server (local) console.